# Jmeter XMPP message information

Tags: jmeter, xmpp

I have set up a Test Plan using Jmeter with XMPP plugin and openfire (as my server) .  When I run my test (using the Jmeter GUI) for each: XMPP Collect Packages Sample I am getting a response data as number of packets received along with packets itself, I need to get the subSample result .

IN BeanShell Sampler I have

```
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;

System.out.println( "myData-->"+SampleResult subResult : 
SampleResult.getSubResults());
```

I keep getting this error:

```
 Typed variable declaration : Cannot reach instance method: getSubResults() from static context: org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult
```

From GUI when I click on the message from collectPackage sampler itself I see:

```
<message id='Q93Ww-102' to='user0@n-dev-xyz' from='user0@n-dev-xyz/jmeter'><body>Hello, it&apos;s user1</body></message>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot do this from the Beanshell Sampler itself, in order to be able to work with the XMPP Sampler sub-results you need:

   - Add Beanshell Post-Processor as a child of the XMPP Sampler. You will be able to access the parent sampler result using `prev` shorthand like:

     ```
     SampleResult [] subResults = prev.getSubResults();
     ```
   - If you still want to use Beanshell Sampler you need to place it **after** the XMPP Sampler and use `ctx` shorthand to access previous sampler result like:

     ```
     SampleResult [] subResults = ctx.getPreviousResult().getSubResults();
     ```
2. Be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it is strongly recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for any form of scripting mainly because [Groovy performance is much better comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) so I would suggest migrating to [JSR223 Post-Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and Groovy on next available opportunity.